# Cannot find 'emailTextField' in scope

Tags: xcode, firebase, authentication

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BHqX.png)

it can't find'emailTextField' in scope, but It works on the signup auth

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post text, not images. And the code in the image is not sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.